# Angular.js low quality image

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have base64 encoded image string, Its quality is 2 mb, And I want to have one more base64 string too whose mb is lower than 50 kb. I couldn't find any solution to get image from base64 string with low quality. How can I do it

```
$scope.SaveImage = function () {
         var desc=$scope.img.Desc
         var SaveList=[];
         for(var i=0;i<Pictures.length;i++){
             var item={
                 taskId:taskId,
                 desc:desc,
                 raw:Pictures[i].image,
                 thumbnail:Pictures[i].image                 
             }
             SaveList.push(item);
         }


         $http.post('http://example.com:3000/photos/',SaveList).success(function(response){ //make a get request to mock json file.          
            var data=response;

            window.location.reload();



        })
        .error(function(err){
           alert(JSON.stringify(err));
        })
    }
```

Code above I have list which containts base64 encoded strings, And I will post data in post item thumbnail must be lower than 50kb.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: use canvas `toDataUrl()` function

Answer (score 0):

You can use `canvas` to reduce the size of image. You can specify *image format* and *image quality* with `canvas.toDataURL()` like :

```
canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg',0.7)
```

You can also use `ng-image-compress` to achive your goal.
[Here](https://github.com/sammychl/ng-image-compress) is the doc for `ng-image-compress`.